# Column insertion disabled in MySQL Workbench

Tags: ubuntu, mysql-workbench

I've just downloaded MySQL Workbench to try out the features since I am messing with MySQL.
The problem I am encountering is that, whenever I create a new table, I cannot add columns to it. The area which (I think) should contain the column information is greyed out.

Also:

```
$ mysql-workbench --version
MySQL Workbench CE (GPL) 6.3.4 0  build 828
```

It is not a permission problem, because I can create the table and then create a hand made sql query to insert the elements. And they appear correctly.

[image: MySQL Workbench]